# shoulda validate_inclusion_of not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, shoulda, rspec3

Recently upgraded a codebase to rails4 along with gems, now we're getting this error.

```
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to ensure_inclusion_of(:usage).in_array(['Index', 'Slide', 'Body']).with_message("%{value} is not a valid usage") }
   ["Index", "Slide", "Body"] doesn't match array in validation
```

and here is the related model code

```
USAGES = ['Index', 'Slide', 'Body']
validates_inclusion_of :usage, :in => USAGES, :message => "%{value} is not a valid usage"
```

Is there something I'm missing? I don't understand why this is failing.

Answer (score 2):

`validate_inclusion_of` uses `allow_value` internally. Admittedly, we should give you a better error message as to what's going on here, but you should be able to write the following tests to figure out what's happening:

```
it { should allow_value("Index").for(:usage) }
it { should allow_value("Slide").for(:usage) }
it { should allow_value("Body").for(:usage) }

it do
  should_not allow_value("something else").
    for(:usage).
    with_message("%{value} is not a valid usage")
end
```

My guess is that shoulda-matchers isn't automatically interpolating the `%{value}` inside of your failure message. If this is true, then what I would do (after [filing an issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues)) is extract the message to an i18n key, and then pass the name of the key to `with_message` instead.

Answer (score 2):

worked for me -

```
expect { should validate_inclusion_of(:usage).in?(['a', 'b']) }
```

Answer (score 0):

should try this -

```
validates :usage, inclusion: { :in => %w( Index Slide Body ), :message => "%{value} is not a valid usage" }
```